# How to append Js variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So I know this question might be asked a lot of times, but I haven't found the right answer yet. The piece of code I am trying to implement in my code is this

```
$('.alert-success').append($('<div/>', { id: element.region, 'class' : 'ansbox'}))
```

How can I put content including js variables inside the div?

Comment: What are you really trying to append? The HTML Code which you want to append?

Comment: I am trying to put content in between this div (a,h2,h4,and small tag )

Comment: so `.alert-success` is a div and you want to append elements to the div?

Comment: Yep like so <a href="element.id">region</a> <h2>element.home_town</h2>

Comment: You can't use append with JS object. According to the documentation, it must be htmlString or Element or Text or Array or jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do it as :

**1) Concatenation**

**2) [Template Literals (ES6)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)**

So template literals is a new EcmaScript 6 (ES6) introduced new feature which is the most easy method and quite clear. While using concatenation you have to keep an eye for alot of quotes stuff. By using Template Literals method you don't need to keep an eye out for single quotes and double quotes stuff. You just need to write your variables properly.

If you want to append a `div` so then try the following as :

```
$('div').append(`<a href="${element.id}">region</a> <h2>${element.home_town}</h2>`);
```

**NOTE :** Replace all your variables with the above syntax as `${your_variable_here}`

Comment: @niksan870 : Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create element string and append it to whatever the element

```
var eleStr = "<div id='"+ element.region +"' class='ansbox'><h1>This is a test</h1></div>";

    $('.alert-success').append(eleStr);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!